# Understanding Haskell's Cast Operator

Tags: haskell

Assume that we have imported `Data.Typeable` which contains `cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) -> a -> Maybe b`.

Consider that

```
> cast 'n' :: Maybe Char
Just 'n'
```

yet

```
> cast 7 :: Maybe Char
Nothing
```

I understand the above, but it seems to be a trivial example. It doesn't reveal why someone would need to use the `cast` operator (as far as I can see).

**Question:** Is there an example of a usage of `cast` which genuinely "changes" the type of a value from one type to another? The closest example I can think of (which doesn't actually work in GHCi) would be changing the type of `7` from `Integer` to `Double`:

```
> cast 7 :: Maybe Double
Just '7' -- this doesn't work, as 7 is typed as a Integer above; instead GHCi returns Nothing
```

Comment: You're probably interested [in this blog post](http://chrisdone.com/posts/data-typeable). It predates `Data.Coerce.coerce`, so some of the things might get done differently today.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there an example of a usage of cast which genuinely "changes" the type of a value from one type to another?

The simple answer is no. But, there may be a situation in which you do not know your type, since it is "hidden" by the quantifier "exists". Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

data Foo = forall a . Typeable a => Foo a

main = print . catMaybes . map (\(Foo x) -> cast x :: Maybe Bool) $ xs
  where
    xs = [Foo True, Foo 'a', Foo "str", Foo False]
```

The output will be:

```
[True,False]
```

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the `Typeable` class is to allow you to work with data when you don't know its exact type. The purpose of the `cast` operator is to check whether some data has a specific type, and if so, let you work with it as that type. It's all about doing stuff to *the type signature* of your data. The actual *value* does not change at all.

If you want to change the *value* of some data, that's not a cast, that's a *conversion*. All sorts of functions out there to do that. E.g., `fromIntegral` turns something that's an instance of `Integral` into something else. (E.g., `Int` to `Double`.) That's not what *casting* is about though.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to implement a function which acts as the identity function on all values, except for integers where it should act as the successor function.

In an untyped language like Python, this is simple:

```py
>>> def f(x):
...   if type(x) == int:
...     return x+1
...   else:
...     return x
... 
>>> f(42)
43
>>> f("qwerty")
'qwerty'
```

Even in Java, this is doable, even if it requires some casting:

```java
static <A> A f(A a) {
    if (a instanceof Integer)
        return (A) (Integer) ((Integer) a + 1);
    else
        return a;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(">> " + f(42));
    System.out.println(">> " + f("qwerty"));
}

/*  Output:
>> 43
>> qwerty
*/
```

What about Haskell?

In Haskell, this can not be done. Any function of type `forall a. a -> a` must either fail to terminate, or behave as the identity. This is a direct consequence of the [free theorem](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) associated to that type.

However, if we can add a `Typeable` constraint on type `a`, then it becomes possible:

```
f :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> a
f x = case cast x :: Maybe Int of
   Nothing -> x
   Just n  -> case cast (n+1) :: Maybe a of
      Nothing -> x
      Just y -> y
```

The first `cast` converts `a` to `Int`, the second `cast` converts `a` back to `Int`.

The code above is quite ugly, since we know that the second cast cannot fail, so there's no real need for the second cast. We can improve the code above with `eqT` and a type-equality GADT:

```
f :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> a
f x = case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: Int) of
   Nothing   -> x
   Just Refl -> x+1
```

Basically, `eqT` tells us whether two (`Typeable`) types are equal. Even better, after matching with `Just Refl`, the compiler also knows that they are equal, and allows us to use `Int` vales instead of `a` values, interchangeably, and with no casts.

Indeed, thanks to GADTs, `:~:` and `eqT`, now most uses of `cast` are now
obsolete. `cast` itself can be trivially implemented with `eqT`:

```
cast :: forall a. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
cast x = case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: b) of
   Nothing   -> Nothing
   Just Refl -> Just x
```

Conclusion: in Haskell, we get the best of both world. We do have parametricity guarantees (free theorems) for polymorphic types. We can also break those parametricity guarantees, and use "ad hoc" polymorphism, at the price of an additional `Typeable` constraint.